# Func<T> scope inside class

Tags: c#, delegates

Why can't I do this?

```
public int FillModel(int id)
{
   // do something...
   return 0;
}

public Func<int, int> actiontest = FilleModel;
```

The code doesn't compile and tells me there is no reference?

Comment: What does compiler say when you remove `public` and change `FilleModel` to `FillModel` ?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

As said *L.B* in his comment you should change:

```
public Func<int, int> actiontest = FilleModel;  //FilleModel doesn't exist
```

with:

```
Func<int, int> actiontest = FillModel;
```

Else if you want to make it public:

```
public Func<int, int> actiontest;

public myClass(){
   actiontest = FillModel;
}
```

Or:

```
public Func<int, int> actiontest = FillModel;

private static int FillModel(int id) //private else the delegate doesn't make sense
{
   // do something...
   return 0;
}
```

Answer (score 0):

One Important thing, apart from changing:

```
public Func<int, int> actiontest = FilleModel;
```

to

```
Func<int, int> actiontest = FillModel;
```

You cannot have a *direct declaration* at the *Class level*. You can only have such declaration inside some behavior `Method` or `Property` setter/getter.